# SQLite Where IN followed by variable String

Tags: android, string, sqlite

I have the variable string (user gets to set it via a ListView with tickboxes, so string can contain any number of fruits)

```
    private static final String kernset = "Banana, Peach"
```

I have the following SQLite Query

```
          Cursor cursor = db.query (TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
        WOORD },
        "kern IN (\"Banana\", \"Apple\")", null, null, null, null, null);
```

I want to replace the (\"Banana\", \"Apple\") part of the query with the variable.

How should I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to place a variable into your `selection` parameter, you can split your string using [split method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), and then form your selection like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("kern IN (");
String[] inItems = kernset.split("\\,\\s+");

for (int i=0; i < inItems.length; i++){
    if (i > 0)
        sb.append(", ");
    sb.append("'" + inItems[i] + "'");
}
sb.append(")");
String selection = sb.toString();
```

however if you wish to use `?` in `selection` and replace it with `selectionArgs[]` it seems to be imposible since values passed in `selectionArgs` are surrounded with `' '`. You can however form selection with `?` instead of actual values (like `kern IN (?, ?, ?)`)and then pass `inItems` via `selectionArgs[]`

Comment: Thanks! Never would have figured this out by my own.. I had to add `sb.append(")");` to get the closing `)`. Current (working) code :
 
 
`      for (int i=0; i < inItems.length; i++){
          if (i > 0)
              sb.append(", ");
          sb.append("'" + inItems[i] + "'");
      }
      sb.append(")");
      String selection = sb.toString();` -- PLEASE edit your solution to add the ), so I can mark it correct. Thanks!

Comment: no problem =) sorry I missed that line while copying the code

Answer (score 0):

by just using concatenation like

```
 Cursor cursor = db.query (TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
    WOORD },
    "kern IN (\""+var1+"\", \""+var2+"\")", null, null, null, null, null);
```

for unknow no of vars

```
inString="";
   for(int i=0;i<fruits.length();i++)
    {
        inString=inString+"\""+fruits[i]+"\"";
        if(i<(fruits.length()-1))
      {
         inString=inString+", "
      }
    }


        Cursor cursor = db.query (TABLE_NAME, new String[] { WOORD },
            "kern IN ("+inString+")", null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: For unknown no of vars; I get errors, missing `;` on line 7, inString cannot be resolved to a variable, Type of expression must be Array, but resolved to String..

Comment: then just put ; after line like  inString=inString+", ";